# Лидер забега или победитель забега

Tags: семантика, синонимы

Если забег продолжается, то мы говорим **лидер забега**. Если же забег закончился, то мы говорим **победитель забега**.
Правильно ли употреблять слово лидер в качестве прямого синонима слова победитель или нет? То есть говорить **лидер забега** на момент когда самого забега уже не существует и определился **победитель забега**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Со словаря:
Лидер — спортсмен или команда, **идущие** первыми в каком-либо состязании. || То есть идущие в данный момент.

Победитель — это экс-лидер, тот, кто лидировал ранее. Условно можно сказать, что он и сейчас лидер, но лишь по отношению к тому, что было в прошлом (и желательно это указать, чтобы не возникло вопросов). И чем больше времени прошло с момента окончания соревнования, тем больше это теряет актуальность. Нельзя назвать такое использование идеальным. Его лучше избегать. Но в разговорном стиле и не такое встречается.

Например, президент — это тоже лидер, но лишь за какой-то период.

И ещё, победитель — это тот, кто победил, а лидер — тот, кто лидирует. Спортсмен может долгое время лидировать, а затем кто-то другой его превзойдёт. Лидировать могут многие (поочерёдно), а победит лишь один. То есть совсем не факт, что лидер станет победителем, но победитель точно был лидером. И если и награждать лидеров забегов, то всех, кто лидировал, а не только одного победителя.

Answer (score 1):

> самого забега не существует

Как-то не очень хорошо сказано. Он прошёл, но остался в истории.

По окончании забега (гонки, заплыва и пр.) неверно говорить *лидер,* только *победитель.*

> Если забег продолжается, то мы говорим лидер забега. Если же забег закончился, то мы говорим победитель забега.

Да, вот тут всё правильно, вы в точку попали!

Лидер ещё может быть рейтинга, например Кубка мира по лыжным гонкам или рейтинга ATP (в теннисе). При этом он может в любой момент смениться (ну не совсем любой, не понимайте настолько буквально) и перестать быть лидером, а победитель, например, забега им и останется, будет одним из победителей этого забега, победителем какого-то года.

Есть ещё понятие *"лидирующая группа"* в циклических видах спорта: велоспорте (лидерский пелотон), беге, лыжных гонках и других. При этом таковую выделяют только в забегах/гонках с общего старта.

---

**Дополнил ответ**

Вот вам статистика: в Нацкорпусе нету ***ни одного*** результата на *"награждение **лидеров**"* и ***29*** вхождений на *"[награждение **победителей**](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9)".*

Теперь [словарь](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/leader) (Макмиллан):

> **leader**
>   2. a person, animal, or vehicle that ***is winning at a particular time during a race or competition***

То есть это человек, животное или машина, ***выигрывающая в определённый момент времени*** в течение гонки или другого состязания.

Comment: Почему тогда новости пестрят фразами типа "Начало награждения лидеров забегов, начиная с детей и далее по взрослым дистанциям"? Общая безграмотность или все таки лидер полноправный синоним победителя?

Comment: Я думаю, скорее безграмотность. Простите, пропустил ваш комментарий и только сейчас поэтому среагировал.

Comment: Право слово не стоило извинений. Формат форума и предполагает ответ в любое удобное время либо его отсутствие. Все сугубо по желанию. А вообще в этом вопросе мне хотелось именно какого-то объективного подтверждения, статистики, ссылки, словарей или перевода из английского словаря. Надо, кстати, заглянуть в английский словарь.

Comment: @user190920: добавил того, что вас интересовало.